# Adding one identityserver as a clinet to another identityserver

Tags: claims-based-identity, identityserver3, claims

How to add one IdentityServer (say idsvr1) as a client to another IdentityServer(say idsvr2)? Is it some thing like the below one? (assuming that the code I am showing below is from idsvr2)

```
 new Client
                {
                    ClientName = "idsvr1",
                    Enabled = true,
                    ClientId = "customclient",
                    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                    { 
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                    },

                    Flow = Flows.Custom,

                    AllowedScopes = new List<string> 
                    {
                        "read"

                    },

                    AllowedCustomGrantTypes = new List<string>
                    {
                        "custom"
                    }
                },
```

When the request comes to IdentityServer1 with a special payload, I want to redirect that call to IdentityServer2. Where to plugin this redirection code in IdentityServer1?

Answer (score 1):

That's right, you would configure a client entry for idsvr1 in idsvr2.

You then need to configure idsvr2 as an external identity provider in idsvr1, the same way you would any other (e.g. Google or Facebook). This would be using the [OpenIdConnectAuthentication](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect) middleware.

See [the docs](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/identityProviders.html) for details on adding an external identity provider to Identity Server.

Comment: What Flow I need to use if I configure idsvr1 as a client in idsvr2? my use case is, creating federated Identity servers. say for example, i have 2 security zones: Zone1 and Zone2. Each Zone has its own Identity Server. If user from Zone2 is trying to access an application in Zone1, then Zone1 Identity server should redirect user to Zone2 Identity Server to get Zone2 token (Similar to ADFS federation).